# Whitelisted chromecast works with default tictactoe app ID but not mine

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am trying to get the tic tac toe demo from github working on my Chromecast after changing only the app id of the clients. With the default app id, I have been able to launch and play the game with an android client and a mac client.

I have:

- Added my Chromecast device on the developer console (it has a green status indicator)
- Set (via the Android Chromecast app) the Chromecast to send the device serial number
- Verified that the serial number is correct
- Verified with both the Android and Windows Chromecast apps that the serial# setting is retained
- Power cycled the Chromecast
- Setup an app id in the developer console (status is a grey circle labeled 'Unpublished')
- Entered an internet accessible (not local) URL for the app id
- Installed the receiver app at the above url and verified I can access it from a browser on the same network as the Chromecast
- Also tried a local IP address (192.168.x.x) which I understand is supported as well
- Modified the web client ttt.js file to use my app id (and verified app id is correct)
- Modified the android client (GameActivity.java) to use my app id (and verified app id)
- Did a git diff to make sure that I didn't inadvertently change anything else
- Verified that my local copy of the source is the latest from git

When running the android client I can connect to my Chromecast but the Chromecast home screen shows "Brain Freeze", "We're sorry, but something could not load", "Activity aborted".

The logcat console in eclipse for the android device reports, "ConnectionResultCallback. Unable to launch the game. `statusCode: 2002`".

The web client on the Mac results in the same messages on the Chromecast and

```
'"reason":"CANCELLED","type":"LAUNCH_ERROR"'
```

on the web page output.

Is there a way to get more information from the Chromecast to indicate what is going wrong with the launch?

**Follow Up**

It turns out that the issue was in my network setup and not in my chromecast setup. After sniffing the network traffic with wireshark, I could see that the ARP request to retrieve the MAC address of my server was not getting a response. I am running my server on Virtualbox with a bridged adapter but needed to turn on promiscuous mode (allow all). Now the chromecast successfully launches the receiver app and I can play the tic tac toe game when using an HTTP based URL. (I need to fix the certificate for HTTPS).

Thanks Les, for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that [x] send my serial # to Google has been checked (using the setup app)?
Also, did you wait 15 minutes and then restart your device (power cycle)?

Comment: Hey Les, yes, I did enable the setting to send the serial number and power cycled the device (items 2-5 listed above). I set the option to send the serial number yesterday and have power cycled the chromecast multiple times since then...

Comment: Using Chrome, can you debug a receiver <ip of Chromecast>:9222 ?  If you can't, check that send your serial# to google is actually set, sometimes they don't get set.

Comment: Hey Les, I have verified that the option to send the serial number is set in both the android app and the windows app. I can access the debugger at that address but it gets disconnected when the app fails to launch.

Comment: Ok - that means you could debug the home screen?  You didn't click Publish, by chance?  If so, then your receiver URL must be HTTPS.  If that isn't it, try writing chromecast-updates@google and see if they can help you.

Comment: Hey, no, my app status indicates "Unpublished". The circle is grey though. I assume that's ok and just indicates it is not published? The URL I'm using does use HTTPS. http s://xxxxxxxx.com/chromecast/ttt/receiver/tictactoe.html. I'm using a dynamic dns service. I'm assuming that isn't an issue or is it?

Comment: I don't know, it really depends on how often it changes.  Is it on the same network as your Chromecast?  You can use any of the local IP address ranges in 192.168.x.x, 10.xx.x.x, or the other one.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel Hey, Les. I have ticked the option to send my Serial Number to Google, my Dev Console says my Chromecast is Ready for Testing but I can't access to <ip of Chromecast>:9222 in the browser. What should I try?

Comment: sorry -- I haven't worked on Chromecast for almost a year now, suggest you send an email to chromecast-updates@google.com and see if the support team responds -- you might need to wait 'til next week.